# FIre event on toggle of v-show

Tags: laravel, vue.js, laravel-blade

I am using Laravel with Vuejs. i want to fire an event on component show or hide. how to achieve this?

```
<album-images v-show ="!gallery"
:album = "album"
:image-arr = "imageArr"></album-images>
```

Comment: when do you want to fire the event? when the user click a button or else?

Comment: how the event should occur ?

Comment: on component show.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a watcher:

```
watch: {
    gallery: {
        handler: value => {
            this.$emit('gallery-toggled', value)
        }
    }
}
```

or a computed:

```
 computed: {
    toggle () {
         this.$emit('gallery-toggled', this.gallery)
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something after the view has updated (i.e the component is actually visible or hidden), you ***may*** have to wrap the $emit in `nextTick()`, see [Vue.nextTick( [callback, context] )](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-nextTick).

It depends on the exact order of updating the watch or computed, but if you are getting unexpected results in the receiver of the event, this is an option to try.

See the discussion [here](https://forum-archive.vuejs.org/post/4081).

```js
this.$nextTick(function() { 
  this.$emit('galleryVisible', this.gallery) 
});
```